# Make eclipse remove unused imports but keep unresolved

Tags: eclipse

**Is there a way to make Eclipse keep used but unresolved imports?**

I'm using Eclipse's save actions to remove unused imports. Unfortunately it also removes imports that are used, but not unresolved.

In the example below, eclipse will remove `GeneratedClass`, if I save `MyClass` before generating the `GeneratedClass`. When I late generate the code, `MyClass` will be missing the import.

```
import a.b.GeneratedClass;
public class MyClass extend GeneratedClass {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Bananeweizen and Krispy for their contributions, but so far it seems that the answer to this question is **No**.

The most efficient work around for me, is just to hit ctrl+z every time I save a file with unresolved imports.

<strike>I have submitted a bug to Eclipse's bugtracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395538</strike>

This Eclipse bug tracks this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357795

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the save macros and instead hit Ctrl-Shift-O which will give you more explicit control over when the imports should be tidied up.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+O` also removes unresolved imports. I can't find a setting in `Preferences->Java->Code Style->Organize Imports` to turn that off. So I am missing how `Ctrl+Shift+O` helps me. Can you explain how I get explicit control?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the clean up action and instead remove the unwanted imports manually one by one using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to invoke the quick fix for that.

Nevertheless you are just trying to hide the real problem. The real problem is that your generated code is not generated at the right time. You should fix that. If you don't know how to automatically involve actions in Eclipse during every project build, please look at [this example](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) (which automatically creates a jar file with a custom script during every build). You can have those builders applied to the project in any order that you want, so you can always have your code generation invoked automatically before the Java compiler, on saving your Java files.

Comment: I'm working with an enterprise build infrastructure that works with multiple IDE's, so I can't really change how stuff is build :(